# Why does my App JS file increase after each run of NPM run dev?

Tags: laravel, npm, webpack, laravel-mix, inertiajs

For some strange reason, whenever I run `npm run dev`, each time, my `/public/js/app.js` file seems to gain a few MB, *regardless of not changing any code*.

**webpack.mix.js**

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .vue()
    .postCss('resources/css/app.css', 'public/css', [
        require('postcss-import'),
        require('tailwindcss'),
    ])
    .webpackConfig(require('./webpack.config'));

if (mix.inProduction()) {
    mix.version();
}

if (!mix.inProduction()) {
    mix.bundleAnalyzer({
        analyzerMode: 'static'
    });
}
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            '@': path.resolve('resources/js'),
        },
    },
};
```

**app.js**

```
require('./bootstrap');

import { createApp, h } from 'vue';
import { createInertiaApp } from '@inertiajs/inertia-vue3';
import { InertiaProgress } from '@inertiajs/progress';

const appName = window.document.getElementsByTagName('title')[0]?.innerText 
    || 'Laravel';

createInertiaApp({
    title: (title) => `${title} - ${appName}`,
    resolve: (name) => require(`./Pages/${name}.vue`),
    setup({ el, app, props, plugin }) {
        return createApp({ render: () => h(app, props) })
            .use(plugin)
            .mixin({ methods: { route } })
            .mount(el);
    },
});


InertiaProgress.init({ color: '#4B5563' });
```

The problem seems to be the `.vue()` in the webpack file, which, when run without, reduces the app.js size down to 700kb. But, of course, without it, I get:

> ERROR in ./resources/js/Pages/Dashboard.vue 1:0 Module parse failed:
> Unexpected token (1:0) You may need an appropriate loader to handle
> this file type. Currently, no loaders are configured to process this
> file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders

**package.json**

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "mix",
        "watch": "mix watch",
        "watch-poll": "mix watch -- --watch-options-poll=1000",
        "hot": "mix watch --hot",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "mix --production"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@inertiajs/inertia": "^0.10.0",
        "@inertiajs/inertia-vue3": "^0.5.1",
        "@inertiajs/progress": "^0.2.6",
        "@tailwindcss/forms": "^0.2.1",
        "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.5",
        "autoprefixer": "^10.2.4",
        "axios": "^0.21",
        "laravel-mix": "^6.0.6",
        "laravel-mix-bundle-analyzer": "^1.0.5",
        "lodash": "^4.17.19",
        "postcss": "^8.2.13",
        "postcss-import": "^14.0.1",
        "tailwindcss": "^2.2.7",
        "vue": "^3.0.5",
        "vue-loader": "^16.1.2"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@headlessui/vue": "^1.4.0",
        "@heroicons/vue": "^1.0.4"
    }
}
```

Please can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: welcome to javascript. What you can do is take two/three version of your app.js and use a tool to compare the two/three example using a tool (online or a diff app). But even then after identifying the culprit, you will have a lot to untangle and is not worth the effort.

Comment: Thanks! The compare worked wonders. I previously renamed a file, which I believe my IDE then renamed a reference incorrectly. I had a Vue file that was importing my app.js by mistake. I feel dumb.

Comment: nice find :) good job